# No routes found in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an ecommerce app where the productsList page renders `ProductCard` component and when I click on any of the productCard on `ProductsList` I should get a `ProductDetail` page. However, I get the `Route` not found error even after trying all the tips on the internet.

AllRoutes.jsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { HomePage, ProductsList, ProductDetail } from "../pages"

export const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}/>
        <Route path="/products" element={<ProductsList />} />
        <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

ProductList.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ProductCard } from "../../components/Elements/ProductCard";
import { FilterBar } from "./components/FilterBar";
import { useTitle } from "../../hooks/useTitle";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProductsList = () => {
  useTitle("Explore eBooks")
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const search = useLocation().search;
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search).get("q")
 
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProducts() {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products?name_like=${query ? 
query : ""}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      setProducts(json)
    }
    fetchProducts()
  }, [query])

  return (
    <main>
      <section className="my-5">
        <div className="my-5 flex justify-between">
          <span className="text-2xl font-semibold dark:text-slate-100 mb-5">All eBooks 
(15)</span>
          <span>
            <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)} id="dropdownMenuIconButton" data- 
   dropdown-toggle="dropdownDots" className="inline-flex items-center p-2 text-sm font- 
  medium text-center text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 dark:text- 
white 
dark:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" type="button"> 
              <svg className="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 
   20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 
12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path></svg>
            </button>
          </span>            
        </div>    

        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center lg:flex-row">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <ProductCard key={product.id} product={product}/>
          ))}
        </div>  
      </section>

      {show && <FilterBar setShow={setShow} />}
    </main> 
  )
}
```

ProductCard.jsx

```
import { Rating } from "./Rating";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  console.log(product.id)
  return (
    <div className="m-3 max-w-sm bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
      <Link to={`products/${product.id}`} className="relative">
        { product.best_seller && <span className="absolute top-4 left-2 px-2 bg-orange-500 bg-opacity-90 text-white rounded">Best Seller</span>}
        <img className="rounded-t-lg w-full h-64" src={product.poster} alt="" />
      </Link>
      <div className="p-5">
        <Link to={`products/${product.id}`}>
          <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{product.name}</h5>
        </Link>
        <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{product.overview}</p>
        
        <div className="flex items-center my-2">
          <Rating rating={product.rating}/>
        </div>

        <p className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <span className="text-2xl dark:text-gray-200">
            <span>$</span><span>{product.price}</span>
          </span>
          <button className="inline-flex items-center py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800">Add To Cart <i className="ml-1 bi bi-plus-lg"></i></button>
          {/* <button className="inline-flex items-center py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-red-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-red-800">Remove Item <i className="ml-1 bi bi-trash3"></i></button> */}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ProductDetail.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Rating } from "../components";
import { useTitle } from "../hooks/useTitle";

export const ProductDetail = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();
  useTitle(product.name)
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProducts(){
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products/${id}`);
      const data = await response.json()
      setProduct(data);
    }
    fetchProducts();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        <h1 className="mt-10 mb-5 text-4xl text-center font-bold text-gray-900 
    dark:text- 
       slate-200">{product.name}</h1>
        <p className="mb-5 text-lg text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-slate-200"> 
          {product.overview}
        </p>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-around">
          <div className="max-w-xl my-3">
            <img className="rounded" src={product.poster} alt={product.name} />
          </div>
          <div className="max-w-xl my-3">
            <p className="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-slate-200">
              <span className="mr-1">$</span>
              <span className="">{product.price}</span>
            </p>
            <p className="my-3"> 
              <span>
                <Rating rating={product.rating} />
              </span>
            </p>
            <p className="my-4 select-none">
              {product.best_seller && <span className="font-semibold text-amber-500 border bg-amber-50 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 mr-2">BEST SELLER</span>}
              {product.in_stock && <span className="font-semibold text-emerald-600 border bg-slate-100 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 mr-2">INSTOCK</span>}
              {!product.in_stock && <span className="font-semibold text-rose-700 border bg-slate-100 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 mr-2">OUT OF STOCK</span>}
              <span className="font-semibold text-blue-500 border bg-slate-100 rounded-lg px-3 py-1 mr-2">{product.size} MB</span>
            </p>
            <p className="my-3">
              <button className={`inline-flex items-center py-2 px-5 text-lg font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800`}>
                Add To Cart 
                <i className="ml-1 bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
              </button>
              {/* <button className={`inline-flex items-center py-2 px-5 text-lg font-medium text-center text-white bg-red-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-red-800`} disabled={ 
           product.in_stock ? "" : "disabled" }>Remove Item <i className="ml-1 bi bi- 
     trash3"> 
                </i> 
              </button> */}
            </p>
            <p className="text-lg text-gray-900 dark:text-slate-200">
              {product.long_description}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main> 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProductCard` is rendering links with ***relative*** paths, so the computed link target isn't what you are expecting. If the current path is `"/products"` and you link to `"products/:productId"` then the resulting path will be `"/products/products/:productId"`.

Use an ***absolute*** link path, e.g. a target path starting from `"/"`, e.g. `"/products/:productId"`.

Example:

```
<Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} className="relative">
  ...
</Link>
```